# Why images from mysql database displayed as broken?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I have stored an image as blob data type in mysql database, but when the image is retrieved it showed as a broken image. I'm not sure what is the wrong with the following code:

```
<?php
$msg = '';
if (isset($_POST['upload'])){
    $image = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $img = file_get_contents($image);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydatabase') or die('Unable To connect');
    $sql = "insert into info (image) values(?)";

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s",$img);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $affected = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    if($affected==1){
        $msg = 'Done';
    }else{
        $msg = 'Failed';
    }
        mysqli_close($con);
}
if (isset($_POST['show'])){
$id=2;
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $con->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['image'] ).'"/>';
mysqli_close($con);
}
    ?>
```

Comment: what is in $result["image"]? Without knowing that it's really impossible to help. P.S. your second query is vulnerable to SQL injection (or it would be if you took the $id from user input, which presumably will be the intention eventually. You should assign $id to it as a parameter, like you do in the first (insert) query.

Comment: Thank you ADyson, I found the mistake. just  changed the data type of image filed from the database to LONGBLOB instead of BLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. just changed the data type of image filed from the database to LONGBLOB instead of BLOB.